# Alter route path within event_subscriber with GET parameters

Tags: 8, routes, event-subscribers

I know I can alter route path with `event_subscriber`

```
class AdminRouteModifier extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.admin.collection')) {
      // Set new path for the route
      $route->setPath('/admin/entity_admin_collection/newpath');
    }
  }

}
```

But I cannot find how to get link with GET parameters:
`/admin/entity_admin_collection/newpath?sort=asc&order=Name`

Is it possible within the `event_subscriber`?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. If this is for incoming requests you don't need to define GET parameters. If this is for outgoing links see for example  https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/menu-api/providing-module-defined-menu-links

Comment: I need to set outgoing links. And I've set it in aforementioned code (without GET parameters). But I don't know how to write correct code `$route->setPath('/admin/entity_admin_collection/newpath?sort=asc&order=Name')`. I found no solution from the link.

Comment: As said the incoming routes are defined without query string. In the mentioned documentation pages you find how to add new menu links with query args and hook_menu_links_discovered_alter() for existing menu links. The following chapters are for local tasks and action links.